# How to send the header ( top line having logo, sign up , search bar ) of a website only once?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am making a website with nodejs server (with express ) . All the pages will have the same header with logo sign up etc. which are send again and again from the server. How to avoid this duplication.

`app.use(express.static("frontend"));`

frontend directory has 'index.html' and 'login.html' (both having the same header

I am open to all the options (changes in frontend/backend).

PS: I just want to send the header only once (not the full website/application). So how does we do that ( sending the header when someone makes an request but on subsequent requests html files will not have any header, the browser will display the content below the header and keep the header intact)

Comment: Your logo must be cached by the browser in the first call. But if you want everything to be fetched just once, you will need to have a Single Page Application (SPA) for that. Vanilla HTML will always fetch the whole page again.

Comment: @ tbking, I just want to send the header only once (not the full website/application). So how does we do that  (so sending the  header when someone makes an request but on subsequent requests  html files will not have any header, the browser will display the content below the header and keep the header intact)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking: You don't.

The HTML to make up a header is generally pretty small. The heavy parts are going to be things like images which are separate URLs that can get cached anyway. It is rarely something worth worrying about.

It's *possible* to avoid resending the data by the use of frames, but that has implications for people linking to content, search engines and general accessibility.

Likewise you can use JavaScript to load the main body of content instead of using a regular link, but that has similar issues unless you combine it with server-side fallbacks (although a lot of the work to mitigate those issues is done for you if you use a framework like Next.js).

Comment: I liked the javascript part. But as you said it is not something to worry about so I will let it remain as it is. So we don't have to worry about caching. Does browser takes care of this itself ?

Comment: A typical default configuration for a webserver will set sensible cache control headers for static resources. You can tweak them for better performance (e.g. make them be cached for longer if you know they will rarely change / have a cache-busting strategy ready for when they do change).

Comment: so the maxAge option in express.static(root, [options]) will do the job. by default its value is 0.